# IE11 is not letting me type into my input fields

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

For the following code, I'm able to type in any text in the input fields when I'm using firefox. However, the same does not hold true in IE11.

```
          <li class="gridster-form"
                aria-labeledby="Gridster Layout Form"
                alt="Tile Display Input column Input Row">
                <span class="dropdown-text">
                    Col <input type="text" value='tiledata.col' ng-model="tiledata.col" size="1" class="input-col ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid">
                    Row <input type="text" value='tiledata.row' ng-model="tiledata.row" size="1" class="input-row ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid">     
                    <i class= "fa fa-arrows"></i>
                </span>
            </li>
```

How can I change this?

Comment: Check your markup with the [validator](https://validator.w3.org/) in the future.

Answer (score 6):

You have a structure like this: `<a href...><input ... /></a>`

**This is NOT VALID**

Since it is not valid, browsers are at liberty to try and make sense of what you meant. Firefox is giving the input elements priority and letting you use them. Internet Explorer is giving the link priority and not letting you use the child inputs.

**Neither browser is correct** as there is no correct answer.

### Fix your HTML.

Comment: you should apply a larger and bolder font to the last sentence.

Comment: @PA. You got it :p

Comment: I took out the anchor tag, but stll the same problem, see the edited code above